# is this method of showing that the almost sure convergence fails correct, and can we use the Borel-Cantelli?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Consider a sequence of independant random variables such that $X_{n} \in\{0,1\}$ almost surely,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=1\right)=\frac{1}{n}, \quad \text { and } \quad \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=0\right)=1-\frac{1}{n} \quad \forall n \geq 1
$$
the sequence $X_{n}$ converges in probability towards $0,$ but not almost surely.

**My attempt :**

$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{k} X_k = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) < 1$

my reasoning is that only $0$ can converge point-wise to zero, $1$ can't.

is this method correct ?

also I was told that one can use the Borel-Cantelli lemma, how so ? I'm only used to proving a.s comvergence using that, not disproving it.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s only converges to $0$ if it is eventually ALWAYS $0$.

So, almost sure convergence to $0$ is equivalent to saying that almost surely, the sequence contains only finitely many $1$'s.

So, to show that the sequence does not almost surely converge to $0$, it is sufficient to show that there is a non-zero probability that the sequence contains infinitely many $1$'s.  You can prove this using the second Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: just making sure I get it, $\sum \mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = +\infty$, therefore by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\mathbb{P}(\limsup X_n = 1) = 1$, and so there is infinitely many one's.

Comment: also, can you please tell me what's wrong with my attempt ?

Comment: That's right, yes.  As for your attempt: I can't quite make sense of it.  Saying that $P(\lim_k X_k=0)=P(X_n=0)$ is not only false... it doesn't actually make sense.  (For which $n$?)

Comment: I get it now, I was confusing between the indices and the $\omega$'s